# Performance: Azure WebSites two instances vs. two Azure WebSites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm running 1 **Standard-tier** Azure WebSites and trying to get rid of recycle issue and unstable connection for whatever reason.

If I add new instance to same region, is there (1) any difference in performance perspective? (2) Do they have same architectural allocation? (3) and which one is more fail-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another instance to the existing web hosting plan **will run on the resources** defined by that plan. e.g. if you have two virtual machines instances for your Standard plan, all the web sites associated with that web hosting plan will run on both virtual machines.

Neither is "more" fail-safe, as websites are offered as a **Platform-as-a-Service**. This means that the servers that are running on are fully managed by Microsoft and are highly available. If you have instance count set to 2, there will always be two instances up, regardless of underlying hardware faults on the Azure fabric.

Source

- [Azure Websites Web Hosting Plans In-Depth Overview](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/)
- [How does Windows Azure heal?](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/FAQ-with-Mark-Russinovich-How-does-Windows-Azure-heal-)